# Using regular expression in CSS pseudo element

Tags: css, regex, pseudo-element, css-content

Not sure this is possible with CSS only, can the `content` of a pseudo selector contain a regular expression?

In this scenario:

```css
.normal-class::before {
  /*content: attr(class); => this works, but outputs both classes */
}


/*  
DOES NOT WORK
.normal-class::before {
  content: attr(class[^=special]); 
}*/

/*  
DOES NOT WORK
.normal-class::before {
  content: attr(class^=special);
}
*/

/*  
DOES NOT WORK
.normal-class::before {
  content: attr(class^=['special']);
}
*/

.normal-class::before {
  content: attr([class^="special"]); /* NOT WORKING EITHER */
}
```

```html
<div class="special-class normal-class"></div>

DESIRED OUTPUT:<br>
special-class
```

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) can help

Comment: @Sfili_81, including it as a selector works, but I need to be inside of the value of content from pseudo selector.

Comment: [attr*=value] ?

Comment: ```[attr*=value]```, as in how?

Comment: @Sfili_81, already did multiple options, including ```attr([class^=special])``` and ```attr([class^='special'])```.

Comment: you cannot do this with CSS

Comment: @TemaniAfif, okay, was afraid so... Thanks for confirming.

Comment: @TemaniAfif, is concatenation possible for ```content``` value?

Comment: @TemaniAfif, sorry, should have tried that, this works: ```content: 'before 'attr(class);```

Answer (score 0):

CSS does not support partially inserting attribute values as content. You can concatenate one or more `attr()` expressions and/or strings interchangeably, but you can't have part of an attribute value.